# Jquery add multiple divs in searchTerm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I find the code in codepen and i made some changes. Search code in here, I just want to search in multiple divs.  As you see .question and .answer divs. Now the code is working for me but I want to add .answer parts in search.

i try to write like multiple selection $([""],[""]) but didnt work for me.

How i write it? Could you please show me some way to do it.

```js
$(".open").click(function() {
  var container = $(this).parents(".topic");
  var answer = container.find(".answer");
  var trigger = container.find(".faq-t");
  

  answer.slideToggle(200);

  if (trigger.hasClass("faq-o")) {
    trigger.removeClass("faq-o");
  } else {
    trigger.addClass("faq-o");
  }

  if (container.hasClass("expanded")) {
    container.removeClass("expanded");
  } else {
    container.addClass("expanded");
  }
});



jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.question').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-search-term', $(this).text().toLowerCase() + $(this).find("ptag").text().toLowerCase());

  });

  $('.live-search-box').on('keyup', function() {

    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $('.question').each(function() {

      if ($(this).filter
('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1) {
        $(this).parent().parent().show();
      } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
      }

    });

  });




$('#control').keyup(function() { 
if ($(this).val().length == 0) { 
$('.show_hide').hide(); } 
else { 
$('.show_hide').show();
 }
 }).keyup();

$('#control').keyup(function() { 
if ($(this).val().length == 0) { 
$('main').css("margin-top","10%"); } 
else { 
$('main').css("margin-top","30px");
 }
 }).keyup();



});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500);
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #444;
}

main {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.live-search-box {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

h1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.topic {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ebebeb;
}

.open {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
}

.open:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.expanded {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.ptag {
  display: none;
}

.question {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #526ee4;
}

.answer {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.faq-t {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -55px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.faq-o {
  top: -50px;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-224deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-224deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-224deg);
  transform: rotate(-224deg);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .faq-t {
    display: none;
  }
  .question {
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
  main {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .answer {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FAQ</title>
  
  
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  





</head>
<style>

</style>
<body>
  <main>
  <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
  <input type="text" name="control" id="control" class="live-search-box" placeholder="Search!" />

<div class="show_hide">
  <div class="topic">

    <div class="open">

      <h2 class="question">1. How can i delete my complaint/comment?<span class="ptag">SIEBEL</span></h2>
      <span class="faq-t"></span>
    </div>
    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="open">
      <h2 class="question">2. I have posted a complaint/comment, but it doesn’t appear on the website. Why? When my complaint will be posted?
</h2><span class="faq-t"></span>
    </div>
    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="open">
      <h2 class="question">3. How can I edit a complaint I posted?
</h2><span class="faq-t"></span>
    </div>
    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="open">
      <h2 class="question">4. How can i find out personal information of another user?
</h2><span class="faq-t"></span>
    </div>
    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="open">
      <h2 class="question">5. How can i contact another user?
</h2><span class="faq-t"></span>
    </div>
    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="open">
      <h2 class="question">2. I have posted a complaint/comment, but it doesn’t appear on the website. Why? When my complaint will be posted?
</h2><span class="faq-t"></span>
    </div>
    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="open">
      <h2 class="question">3. How can I edit a complaint I posted?
</h2><span class="faq-t"></span>
    </div>
    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="open">
      <h2 class="question">4. How can i find out personal information of another user?
</h2><span class="faq-t"></span>
    </div>
    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="open">
      <h2 class="question">5. How can i contact another user?
</h2><span class="faq-t"></span>
    </div>
    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</main>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
  <script  src="js/index.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code.I added 'data-search-term' for answer.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.question,.answer').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('data-search-term', $(this).text().toLowerCase() + $(this).find("ptag").text().toLowerCase());

    });

    $('.live-search-box').on('keyup', function () {

        var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('.question').parent().hide();
        $('.topic').each(function () {

            if ($(this).find('.question').filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || $(this).find('.answer').filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0) {
                $(this).show();
                $(this).find('.open').show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide();
            }

        });

    });




    $('#control').keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $('.show_hide').hide();
            $('main').css("margin-top", "10%");
        }
        else {
            $('.show_hide').show();
            $('main').css("margin-top", "30px");
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much..  And i also learn how i write it.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this page on how to use multiple selectors https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: i tried every step at there .Something  block the code when i change the selector,